# Нужна ли запятая: "продукция(,) нетрадиционная для данного предприятия"?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Нужна ли запятая и как пишется **не**?

> Основную тенденцию улучшения
> экологической обстановки связывают с
> поступлением продукции (?) не
> традиционной для данного предприятия.

Спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Основную тенденцию улучшения экологической обстановки связывают с поступлением продукции, нетрадиционной для данного предприятия.*